# JavaFX Combination Key problem with 2 directional Key

Tags: java, javafx

I have a question about the javafx library, especially on the keyboard key combination, to creat a controler for a spaceship. In fact I cannot achieve a combination of the Up arrow and right arrow keys(for moving in "translation"). I find only for the keys traditionally used as crtl or alt. But it's doesn't work with UP or KP_UP.
So I try: `KeyCombination keyCombinationUpRight = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.KP_UP, KeyCodeCombination.KP_RIGHT);`
Or :  `if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT || keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.UP){}`

If someone knows a way to achieve it, I'm interested. 
Thank you in advance for your answer.

My code:

```
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCodeCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.scene.shape.Sphere;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

public class Main extends Application {
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Sphere sphere = new Sphere(50);

        Group group = new Group();
        group.getChildren().add(sphere);

        Scene scene = new Scene(group , 1400,1000);

        scene.setOnKeyPressed((final KeyEvent keyEvent) -> {
            if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT ) {
                x=x+5;
                sphere.setTranslateX(x);
            } else if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {
                x=x-5;
                sphere.setTranslateX(x);
            }else if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
                y=y-5;
                sphere.setTranslateY(y);
            } else if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
                y = y + 5;
                sphere.setTranslateY(y);
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setTitle("Vaisseau");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the input ideas from https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-javafx-for-game-development--cms-23835 and that should solve your problem.